# How to evaluate a SQL Server string with a PHP function?

Tags: php, sql, function, sqlsrv

I have the following PHP function that should evaluate a string, to check "if it exists in the database or not" the string comes to the `$row` variable as an email format. I put Pseudo code in the `if` statement. Please help and thank you!

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
    $lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    checkUsername($firstName, $lastName, $username);
    }

function checkUsername($firstName, $lastName, $username){
include 'connect_sql.php'; 

        $sql = "SELECT UserName FROM [Membership].[dbo].[Center] WHERE UserName='$username'";
        $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
        $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);

        if(<$row is true and identical>) {              
            echo "<div id='loginmsg'>Member already exist</div>";
        }

        else {
            echo "<div id='loginmsg'>Member is new</div>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: `var_dump($row)` would probably answer your question... and the mere fact that a row WAS avaialble to be fetched tells you that the query matched SOMETHING.

Comment: @u_mulder How can I evaluate the $row variable with the if condition? I tried the following (sqlsrv_num_rows($row) > 0 ) ahving fetch a row but it jumps to else condition

Comment: @MarcB how would you adapt that in the code?

Comment: You dont actually need to look at the result row, if you got 1 result, then EXISTS, else new member. Look into mysqli_result::$num_rows AKA 
mysqli_num_rows

Comment: @DuaneLortie so do you mean to take out the if and else and just do echo?

Answer (score 2):

If you read `sqlsrv_fetch_array` description you will see this in [return values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-fetch-array.php#refsect1-function.sqlsrv-fetch-array-returnvalues)

> Returns an array on success, NULL if there are no more rows to return, and FALSE if an error occurs.

So, if your query finds a row where `UserName='$username'` what will be returned by `sqlsrv_fetch_array`? `ARRAY`.

If your query finds no rows where `UserName='$username'` what will be returned by `sqlsrv_fetch_array`? `NULL`.

So, your `$row` variable is either `array` or `null`. (Of course it can be `false` in case of error and you can check it too). So you have to check if your `$row` is null or not. This can be done with:

```
if ($row) {
    echo "<div id='loginmsg'>Member already exist</div>";
} else {
    echo "<div id='loginmsg'>Member is new</div>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I see your point but it didn't work. The string comes in with your code but it goes to else condition. Thumbs up for your answer.

Comment: If `else` branch works then you don't have a record what you need. Check your query text, run it directly on sql and see the results.

Comment: I ran it directly at the sql server and the query is fine. I wish there was more documentation about the SQLSRV functions. I tried everything but no luck.